# Kivy TextInput how to change hint_text font size

Tags: kivy, font-size, textinput

Is there a way to change a TextInput hint_text font size in Kivy? I could not find any documentation on using something as `hint_text_size`.

```
TextInput:
    id: text_input_unique
    hint_text: 'example: Stand25'
    hint_text_size: 16
    multiline: False
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    font_size: 32
    halign: 'center'
    cursor_color: (0,0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextInput` uses the same font properties for `hint_text` as it does for the main text (except for color). Here is an extension of `TextInput` that honors a `hint_font_size` property:

```
class TextInputwHintSize(TextInput):
    hint_font_size = NumericProperty(sp(15))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.regular_font_size = sp(15)
        self.ignore_font_size_change = False
        super(TextInputwHintSize, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_font_size)

    def set_font_size(self, dt):
        self.ignore_font_size_change = True
        if self.text == '':
            self.font_size = self.hint_font_size

    def on_font_size(self, instance, size):
        if self.ignore_font_size_change:
            return
        self.regular_font_size = size


    def on_text(self, instance, text):
        if text == '':
            self.font_size = self.hint_font_size
        else:
            self.font_size = self.regular_font_size
```

for example, use this like:

```
TextInputwHintSize:
    id: text_input_unique
    hint_text: 'example: Stand25'
    hint_font_size: 16
    multiline: False
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    font_size: 32
    halign: 'center'
    cursor_color: (0,0,0,1)
```

Comment: I tried changing the `regular_font_size` to 32 and it stays at 15. Is there something I need to do with the `instance` argument?

Comment: I updated the code to better handle 'kv` and python code.

Comment: Thank you that works much better. There are a couple things I will want to refine, but for now it works. I'd like to make it so that when the cursor is on the textinput that it blinks at the a 32 font size. Cheers!